# Form for Searching and data editing in Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I am trying to create a form where I will search for a value in a table "Request Table" search in column "ECN #". When the field is searched I would then be able to populate different areas of the table from that form and save the record. The issue I'm running into is "ECN #" is my primary key and when it is linked to the form it is not a searchable or editable field. If anyone could please help I would greatly appreciate it.

I have tried to create a query (not sure I did it correctly) and then create a form based off of that but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: This is more of a design than coding issue and question is not really appropriate for SO. Suggest you post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis. Strongly advise not to use space nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: if you want to change ecn# create an autonumber and use that as the actual primary key.  next break the problem in two.  use an unbound combobox or textbox to filter the form:  here is one example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uq3cgaHF6fc  usually the form will be bound to some table or query and you can just edit the record directly once you find it.  you probably need to clarify the question at that point.